# Checking how many fields have changed upon saving a form

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I am saving records in a transaction using symfony1.4 and Doctrine.

The rows inserted are coming from a CSV file which is updated regularly. I have already got a method that checks if the records in the CSV match that in the DB and do not insert.

What I'm ideally wanting to do though, is to set a user flash telling them how many rows have been updated whenever they import the CSV file.

```
            $conn = ProductTable::getInstance()->getConnection();
            $conn->beginTransaction();

            try {
                $row = 1;
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    if ($row > 1) {
                        $values = array(
                            'blah'            => null
                        );

                        $obj= ProductTable::getInstance()->findOrCreateNewProduct(
                            $values['blah']
                        );


                        $obj->merge($values);
                        $obj->save($conn);
                    }

                    $row++;
                }

                $conn->commit();

            } catch (Doctrine_Exception $e) {
                $conn->rollback();

                throw $e;
            }
```

I'm wondering how I'd get these updated fields. Is it in the `actions.class.php` or is it in the actual `form.class.php` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the you can call a `Doctrine_Record::getModified()` which will give you an array of fields modified (with their values though that doesnt matter for you). Then you can call count on the returned array and keep a cumulative total outside your loop.

```
        $conn = ProductTable::getInstance()->getConnection();
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        $nbModified = 0;

        try {
            $row = 1;
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                if ($row > 1) {
                    $values = array(
                        'blah'            => null
                    );

                    $obj= ProductTable::getInstance()->findOrCreateNewProduct(
                        $values['blah']
                    );


                    $obj->merge($values);
                    $nbModified += count($obj->getModified());
                    $obj->save($conn);
                }

                $row++;
            }

            $conn->commit();

            // return $nbModified or otherwise do something with it here

        } catch (Doctrine_Exception $e) {
            $conn->rollback();
            // youre rolling back so just for consistency set $nbModified to zero
            $nbModified = 0;

            throw $e;
        }
```

Comment: Where would I put the `Doctrine_Record::getModified()'? within the loop? Thanks

Comment: Seems to work when I update the fields of my CSV and re-upload. Thank you.

Comment: As in the primary record youre saving or including updates to relations as well?

Comment: Well let's  say I have 10 rows in my db. The CSV file has 5. If I then parse the CSV and 3 rows are different in the CSV to that of the db, then I'd like to push '3 rows have been updated' to the user using a flash message.